# Only month end values for each identifier

Tags: sql

For the code below I am attempting to select only the month end values for all unique FundId's. The code below keeps giving me the error of

Msg 164, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference.

How can I fix the where statement to pull all month end values for each fundid

```
SELECT TOP 10000 a.[PerformanceId]
      ,[InvestmentType]
      ,[EndDate]
      ,a.[CurrencyId]
      ,[AssetValue]
      ,c.FundId
  FROM [StatusData_DMWkspaceDB].[dbo].[NetAssetsValidationFailure] a
  LEFT JOIN MappingData_GAPortDB.dbo.PerformanceLevelMapping b
  ON a.PerformanceId = b.PerformanceId
  LEFT JOIN MappingData_GAPortDB.dbo.FundClassMatching c
  ON b.SecId = c.SecId
  WHERE a.EndDate IN (
    SELECT MAX(a.EndDate)
    From [StatusData_DMWkspaceDB].[dbo].[NetAssetsValidationFailure]
    GROUP BY c.FundId, Month(a.EndDate), YEAR(a.EndDate))
```

Comment: Add the tag for your dbms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT TOP 10000 navf.[PerformanceId], [InvestmentType], [EndDate],
       navf.[CurrencyId], [AssetValue], fcm.FundId
FROM [StatusData_DMWkspaceDB].[dbo].[NetAssetsValidationFailure] navf LEFT JOIN
     MappingData_GAPortDB.dbo.PerformanceLevelMapping plm
     ON navf.PerformanceId = plm.PerformanceId LEFT JOIN
     MappingData_GAPortDB.dbo.FundClassMatching fcm
     ON l.m.SecId = fcm.SecId
WHERE navf.EndDate IN (SELECT MAX(navf.EndDate)
                       From [StatusData_DMWkspaceDB].[dbo].[NetAssetsValidationFailure] navf
                       GROUP BY fcm.FundId, Month(navf.EndDate), YEAR(navf.EndDate)
                     );
```

Learn to use sensible table aliases, so the query is easier to write and to read.

In any case, your `WHERE` clause is only referencing *outer* tables in the `GROUP BY`.  The message is quite clear.

I'm not even sure what you want to do, but I am guessing that this is a working version of what you want:

```
SELECT x.*
FROM (SELECT navf.[PerformanceId], [InvestmentType], [EndDate],
             navf.[CurrencyId], [AssetValue], fcm.FundId,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY fcm.FundId, Month(navf.EndDate), YEAR(navf.EndDate)
                                ORDER BY navf.EndDate DESC
                               ) as seqnum
      FROM [StatusData_DMWkspaceDB].[dbo].[NetAssetsValidationFailure] navf LEFT JOIN
           MappingData_GAPortDB.dbo.PerformanceLevelMapping plm
           ON navf.PerformanceId = plm.PerformanceId LEFT JOIN
           MappingData_GAPortDB.dbo.FundClassMatching fcm
           ON l.m.SecId = fcm.SecId
     ) x
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```